# SQL query to fetch unconnected user list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table called Users & Connections[image]

I need to fetch the users list how have not connected from user Table

E.g userid 1 has sent request & connected to 4 & 6. So how to write a query to fetch other users not connected with userid(1).

Expected Result will be userid =1

```
2      bb     b@a.com 
3      cc     c@c.com 
5      ff
```

answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

straightforward woulb be:

```
SELECT * from users a
WHERE userid != :userid
  AND not exists (select * from connections
                   where (userid = :userid and c_userid = a.userid)
                     or  (userid = a.userid and c_userid = :userid))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will return all users that are not in the connections table.

```
SELECT * FROM users AS u
    WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM connections AS c
        WHERE c.userid=u.userid AND reqType != 0) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

below query get user that not associated with userid =1

```
select u.userid,u.name,u.email
from connections
left join users as u on connections.c_userid = u.userid
where connections.userid =1 and connections.reqtype in (0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You try this query

```
select *from users where userid not in (select c_userId from connenctions where where userid=1) and userid!=1
```